# Filtering and Referencing Array to an Object Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, lodash

I have 2 arrays:

Time Stamp Array:

```
var timeStamp = [["0:00","1:00"], ["2:00","3:00"]];
```

Time Label Reference:

```
var timeLabels = [
 { name: "0:00", present: true, label: ["0:00", "1:00"], alterName:"" }, 
 { name: "1:00", present: true, label: ["1:00", "2:00"], alterName:"" }, 
 { name: "2:00", present: true, label: ["2:00", "3:00"], alterName:"" }]
```

I wanted to use `Lodash` to filter through the TimeStamp array but the methods I want are exclusive to object arrays. I currently have a for loop and it is not very elegant.

Ultimately, I want to create a TimeLabels object array thats `present` field is set to True or False if the time is present in the `first index` of timeStamp.

Referencing the Time Stamp Array above, the result would be:

```
var timeResult = [
 { name: "0:00", present: true, label: ["0:00", "1:00"], alterName:"" }, 
 { name: "1:00", present: false, label: ["1:00", "2:00"], alterName:"" }, 
 { name: "2:00", present: true, label: ["2:00", "3:00"], alterName:"" }]
```

I'm more used to using lodash but I'm wondering if other methods would be better to construct the solution or if a for loop, which I'm currently using is ok.

Comment: What methods in lodash are you talking about? There shouldn't be any that are exclusive to arrays. Also, most methods in lodash you can achieve native in arrays in modern browsers i.e. map, reduce, filter, forEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreach elment inside `timeLabels` use `indexOf` to determine whether  `label` is present or not in `timestamp`.To use indexOf you have to convert object into string using `JSON.stringify()`.

```js
var timeLabels = [
 { name: "0:00", present: true, label: ["0:00", "1:00"], alterName:"" }, 
 { name: "1:00", present: true, label: ["1:00", "2:00"], alterName:"" }, 
 { name: "2:00", present: true, label: ["2:00", "3:00"], alterName:"" }];
 
 timeStamp = [["0:00","1:00"], ["2:00","3:00"]];
 
results = timeLabels.forEach(function(res){
 label = JSON.stringify(res.label);//converts into string
 ts = JSON.stringify(timeStamp);//converts into string
 if(ts.indexOf(label)>=0){ //checks whether label is present or not
 res.present = true;
 }
 else{
 res.present = false;
 }
});
console.log(timeLabels);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) to iterate and return  each of the transformed `item`. Notice that I used [assign](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assign) instead of manually assigning the `present` property, this is to avoid mutating the objects inside the `timeLabels` collection. Lastly, we use the combination of [intersectionWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersectionWith) and [isEmpty()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEmpty) to get the `present` value (Note that the resulting value is negated).

```
var timeResult = _.map(timeLabels, function(item) {
  return _.assign({}, item, {
    present: !_(timeStamp)
      .intersectionWith([item.label], _.isEqual)
      .isEmpty()
  });
});
```

```js
var timeStamp = [
  ["0:00", "1:00"],
  ["2:00", "3:00"]
];

var timeLabels = [{
    name: "0:00",
    present: true,
    label: ["0:00", "1:00"],
    alterName: ""
  },
  {
    name: "1:00",
    present: true,
    label: ["1:00", "2:00"],
    alterName: ""
  },
  {
    name: "2:00",
    present: true,
    label: ["2:00", "3:00"],
    alterName: ""
  }
];

var timeResult = _.map(timeLabels, function(item) {
  return _.assign({}, item, {
    present: !_(timeStamp)
      .intersectionWith([item.label], _.isEqual)
      .isEmpty()
  });
});

console.log(timeResult);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tmpTimeStamp = timeStamp.map(function(ts){ return ts[0]+"_"+ts[1] });
timeResult = timeResult.map(function(t){
  t.present = tmpTimeStamp.indexOf(t.label[0]+"_"+t.label[1]) > -1;
  return t;
});
```